# Celery - unable to start worker

Tags: python, celery

I'm using Python 3.2 and I wanted to check out celery.
I used pip to install everything and craeted a tasks.py just like in the tutorial:
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#installing-celery

However if i start a celery worker i get the following:

```
[2013-01-16 10:50:16,552: WARNING/MainProcess] C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\bil
liard\__init__.py:318: RuntimeWarning: force_execv is not supported as the billi
ard C extension is not installed
  warnings.warn(RuntimeWarning(W_NO_EXECV))
[2013-01-16 10:50:16,604: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@LNGVIEW201 ready.
[2013-01-16 10:50:16,651: ERROR/MainProcess] Unrecoverable error: error('char fo
rmat requires a bytes object of length 1',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\celery\worker\__init__.py", line 348, in s
tart
    component.start()
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\celery\worker\consumer.py", line 392, in s
tart
    self.reset_connection()
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\celery\worker\consumer.py", line 738, in r
eset_connection
    self.connection = self._open_connection()
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\celery\worker\consumer.py", line 804, in _
open_connection
    callback=self.maybe_shutdown,
 File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\kombu\connection.py", line 368, in ensure_
connection
    interval_start, interval_step, interval_max, callback)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\kombu\utils\__init__.py", line 217, in ret
ry_over_time
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\kombu\connection.py", line 241, in connect

    return self.connection
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\kombu\connection.py", line 731, in connect
ion
    self._connection = self._establish_connection()
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\kombu\connection.py", line 690, in _establ
ish_connection
    conn = self.transport.establish_connection()
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\kombu\transport\pyamqp.py", line 107, in e
stablish_connection
    heartbeat=conninfo.heartbeat)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\amqp-1.0.6-py3.2.egg\amqp\connection.py",
line 155, in __init__
    self._x_start_ok(d, login_method, login_response, locale)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\amqp-1.0.6-py3.2.egg\amqp\connection.py",
line 762, in _x_start_ok
    args.write_table(client_properties)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\amqp-1.0.6-py3.2.egg\amqp\serialization.py
", line 317, in write_table
    table_data.write_table(v)
   File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\amqp-1.0.6-py3.2.egg\amqp\serialization.py
", line 296, in write_table
     table_data.write(pack('>cB', 't', int(v)))
struct.error: char format requires a bytes object of length 1
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\billiard\forking.py", line 528, in main
     self = load(from_parent)
 TypeError: Required argument 'handle' (pos 1) not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
 File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
 File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
 File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\billiard\forking.py", line 528, in main
 File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\billiard\forking.py", line 528, in main
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\billiard\forking.py", line 528, in main
   self = load(from_parent)
    self = load(from_parent)
  TypeError: Required argument 'handle' (pos 1) not found
    self = load(from_parent)
   TypeError: Required argument 'handle' (pos 1) not found
   TypeError: Required argument 'handle' (pos 1) not found
   Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
 File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\billiard\forking.py", line 528, in main
   self = load(from_parent)
   TypeError: Required argument 'handle' (pos 1) not found
   Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
 File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\billiard\forking.py", line 528, in main
    self = load(from_parent)
   TypeError: Required argument 'handle' (pos 1) not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\billiard\forking.py", line 528, in main
    self = load(from_parent)
TypeError: Required argument 'handle' (pos 1) not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
   File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\billiard\forking.py", line 528, in main
self = load(from_parent)
TypeError: Required argument 'handle' (pos 1) not found
```

Now I guess the clue is alraedy in the first couple of lines:

```
[2013-01-16 10:50:16,552: WARNING/MainProcess] C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\bil
liard\__init__.py:318: RuntimeWarning: force_execv is not supported as the billi
ard C extension is not installed
  warnings.warn(RuntimeWarning(W_NO_EXECV))
```

Can anyone tell me how I install C-Extension for billiard ?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using Windows, if this is the case take a look here

https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1071

There are some issues in the installation on Windows, and seems that there isn't a solution yet.